# How to join two tables without duplicates

Tags: mysql, join

I have an `income` table that looks like this:

```
date              income      
---------------------------
09/05/13          56000    
09/05/13          66600
09/05/13          50000
```

And an `expense` table that looks like this:

```
date              expense 
----------------------------
09/05/13          68800
```

I want to write a query whose output looks like this:

```
date              income             expense 
---------------------------------------------
09/05/13          56000              68800
09/05/13          66600
09/05/13          50000
```

with each value from `income.income` and each value from `expense.expense` appearing only once. (If I do a simple join, then each one will appear three times, since `income.date` and `expense.date` have duplicate values.)

Comment: What are you considering to be a duplicate? The same date and income?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: @BrianHoover: I've edited the question to clarify what the OP must mean.

Comment: I can't think of a simple "pure SQL" way to do this. A front end  (PHP, Python, etc) can help you. If you sum the daily values, a "pure SQL" solution can be written. But... as ruakh said: What have you tried? Please read this article: http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: Are you saying that `income = 56000` needs to end up in the same row as `expense = 68800`? If so -- how did you determine that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try just like this without any unique id's, then your full concept is wrong. Add some unique id's to your table and do the necessary coding.

If you have table structure like below your can write query with simple equi join.
Income_tbl:

```
date              income  id    
---------------------------
09/05/13          56000   1 
09/05/13          66600   2
09/05/13          50000   3
```

Expense_tbl:

```
date              expense  id
----------------------------
09/05/13          68800    1
09/05/13                   2
09/05/13                   3
```

(or) try @Brian Hoover's query it will work.

```
 SELECT income.date_col, income.income, expense.expense
FROM (
        SELECT i.date_col, i.income, @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number
        FROM Income_tbl i
        JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
     ) AS income
JOIN (
        SELECT e.date_col, e.expense, @curExpenseRow := @curExpenseRow + 1 AS row_number
        FROM Expense_tbl e
        JOIN (SELECT @curExpenseRow := 0) r
     ) AS expense
ON income.row_number = expense.row_number;
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to calculate the sum (grouped by date) and join them. You'll need three queries to represent the three data sets you have: A dates set, an income set and an expenses set.

First: The dates set

```
select distinct `date`
from (select `date` from income union select `date` from expense)
```

Second: The income set:

```
select `date`, sum(i.income) as income
from income as i
group by `date`
```

Third: The expenses set:

```
select `date`, sum(e.expense) as expense
from expense as e
group by `date`
```

Finally: Put it all together:

```
select 
    d.date, i.income, e.expense
from
    (
        select distinct `date` 
        from (select `date` from income union select `date` from expense)
    ) as d
    left join (
        select `date`, sum(i.income) as income
        from income as i
        group by `date`
    ) as i on d.`date` = i.`date`
    left join (
        select `date`, sum(e.expense) as expense
        from expense as e
        group by `date`
    ) as e on d.`date` = e.`date`
```

Comment: But that won't give the specified output . . .

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the output you asked for, but it's REALLY brittle.

```
SELECT income.date, income.income, expense.expense
FROM (
SELECT i.date, i.income, @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number
FROM income i
JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0) r) AS income
JOIN (
SELECT e.date, e.expense, @curExpenseRow := @curExpenseRow + 1 AS row_number
FROM expense e
JOIN (SELECT @curExpenseRow := 0) r) AS expense
ON income.row_number = expense.row_number
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75d4f/4)

It's assuming that you have the same number of rows for income and expenses and the order of the income and expenses are the same, so it's merging the results by row number.

What you really need is some sort of way to join the income and expenses, maybe a ledger entry ID or something on each row.  This would give you a definitive join, compared to the hacked join that is in the query I posted.

Comment: Re: "It's assuming that [...] the order of the income and expenses are the same": I don't see any ordering at all . . .

Comment: @ruakh It's using the default order, which is how the data was inserted.  With the data that's posted, there really isn't any other possible ordering.

Comment: That will depend on the storage engine; MySQL itself does not guarantee any "default order" whatsoever.

Comment: @ruakh - hence the disclaimer that this is a very brittle solution and not recommended.  We could order by date, but that would be even more random.  Ideally, at the very least, the date field would be a date/time and the order would then be on that field, but that was not said by the original post.

Comment: Hmm. I guess to me "brittle" means something like "usually works, but makes some assumptions about the data", whereas your solution is more like "meaningless, but sometimes happens to work".

Answer (score 0):

If you want individual entries, you need something like this:

```
select date, income, expense
from
  (
    select
      if(@iId_last = incomeId, null, a.income) as income,
      if(@eId_last = expenseId, null, a.expense) as expense,
      a.date,
      @iId_last := a.incomeId as incomeId,
      @eId_last := a.expenseId as expenseId
    from 
      (select @d := '0000-00-00', @iId_last := -1, @eId_last := -1) as init,
      (
        select 
          d.*, 
          coalesce(i.incomeId,0) as incomeId, income, 
          coalesce(e.expenseId,0) as expenseId, expense
        from
          (
            select distinct date from (select incomeDate as date from income union select expenseDate as date from expense) as d
          ) as d
          left join income as i on d.date = i.incomeDate
          left join expense as e on d.date = e.expenseDate
        order by d.date, incomeId, expenseId
      ) as a
    order by date, incomeId, expenseId
  ) as r;
```

Notice that this solution requires that both `income` and `expense` tables have an Id. Check [SQL Fiddle solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eaec9/15) (I've tested with some combinations: Many income rows and one expense row, one income row and many expenses rows, no income rows and some expenses rows, one income row and no expense rows).

Answer (score 0):

If you're not concerned with particular order in which income values are matched to expense values you can get your desired output with a query like this

```
SELECT date, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN amount END) income,
       MAX(CASE WHEN type = 2 THEN amount END) expense
  FROM
(
  SELECT 1 type, date, income amount, @n := IF(@g = date, @n + 1, 1) rnum, @g := date g
    FROM income CROSS JOIN (SELECT @n := 0, @g := NULL) i1
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, date, expense amount, @m := IF(@f = date, @m + 1, 1) rnum, @f := date g
    FROM expense CROSS JOIN (SELECT @m := 0, @f := NULL) i2
) q
 GROUP BY date, rnum
```

Output:

```
|               DATE | INCOME | EXPENSE |
|--------------------|--------|---------|
| September, 05 2013 |  56000 |   68800 |
| September, 05 2013 |  66600 |  (null) |
| September, 05 2013 |  50000 |  (null) |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/280dd/10)** demo

Comment: thanks a lot. Could you elaborate just a bit what is happening here?